# Where does the static requirement come from?

Tags: rust, static

I have a [very small repo](https://github.com/coriolinus/trait-bound-pretty) which currently does not compile, with the following error:

```
error[E0597]: `line` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:19:20
   |
19 |         let line = line.trim();
   |                    ^^^^-------
   |                    |
   |                    borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                    argument requires that `line` is borrowed for `'static`
...
22 |     }
   |     - `line` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I've had trouble producing a minimal example demoing the problem: [this (playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f503333d8242bff149c399c1670e9a22) works as expected, despite that `fn main` is identical to the one which fails, as are the signatures of `ItemParser::parse` and `Item::pretty_to`.

Inlining a section of `fn main`, and some signatures:

```rust
    let parser = ItemParser::new();

    let stdin = stdin();
    let reader = stdin.lock();
    let reader = BufReader::new(reader);

    let stdout = stdout();
    let mut writer = stdout.lock();
    for line in reader.lines() {
        let line = line?;
        let line = line.trim();
        let item = parser.parse(line)?;
        item.pretty_to(&mut writer)?;
    }
```

The same issue persists when I comment out `item.pretty_to(&mut writer)?;`, so I believe that that isn't the problem.

I can't show the actual code for `ItemParser` as it's generated by [LALRPOP](https://crates.io/crates/lalrpop), but the signature as reported by rustdoc is

```rust
pub struct ItemParser { /* fields omitted */ }

pub fn parse<'input>(
    &self,
    input: &'input str
) -> Result<Item<'input>, ParseError<usize, Token<'input>, &'static str>>
```

Unlike [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58436950/argument-requires-that-is-borrowed-for-static-how-do-i-work-round-this), nothing in this crate explicitly requires a `'static` lifetime.

My expectation is that at the head of the `for` loop, `item` has type `io::Result<String>`. After we discard the error and trim the edges, it should have type `&'a str`, where `'a` is the lifetime scoped to this iteration of the `for` loop. In that case, parsing the line should produce an `Item<'a>` with the same lifetime. It drops before the lifetime ends, in appropriate sequence. As nothing visibly requests a `'static` lifetime, I don't know where that requirement is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On error, `parser.parse()` yields a type that is bounded to the lifetime of the input.

```
Result<Item<'input>, ParseError<usize, Token<'input>, &'static str>>
                                    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You're using `?` to return the error from main (not "discard" it), which by necessity will outlive the loop, and therefore `line`.

You can handle the error immediately via `match` or `if let`, or do something like `parser.parse().map_err(...)?` to transform the error into something not bounded to the lifetime of `line`.

---

Answering the title specifically, The `'static` requirement is from using `eyre::Result` which is an alias for `Result<T, E = Report>`. `Report` can be [created from any `Error` type](https://docs.rs/eyre/0.6.1/eyre/struct.Report.html#impl-From%3CE%3E) (which `ParseError` [is](https://github.com/lalrpop/lalrpop/blob/dd87e0eef3bc516853a1ea01ac1ec6d21ef1c749/lalrpop-util/src/lib.rs#L144)), but is constrained to be `'static`. It is a shame the compiler doesn't bring this up though.

Comment: Thanks! Of course, I should have realized that I had to consider the lifetimes in the `Err(_)` case also.

Answer (score -1):

Since `str` is a sort of slice, it can not outlive its parent. The result on trim is really just a slice the original string.

```rust
pub fn trim(&self) -> &str

// Now with the implicit lifetimes
pub fn trim<'a, 'b: 'a>(&'b self) -> &'a str
```

Since none of the lifetimes of the function arguments would not make appropriate bounds for the lifetime of the function output, it must have a different lifetime and the only appropriate lifetime for an unconstrained reference is `'static`.

Its basically the equivalent to returning a reference to data you just freed in c.

```c
Foo *data_to_return = &foo->bar;
free(foo);
return data_to_return;
```

But it's kinda a moot point anyway because the function would never work in the first place. The lifetime is more of a symptom of your issue than the cause. Just ignore the lifetime for now since it sounds like its holding you up from actually fixing the issue. Once you fix your code, the `'static` bound will go away.

Comment: I'm not asking anything to outlive its parent, though. `item` is constrained by the lifetime of `line`; it lives just long enough to call `pretty_to`, then drops. `line` should drop immediately thereafter and be recreated on the next iteration of the loop.