# Rust lifetime syntax when borrowing variables

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime, borrow

New to Rust and trying to teach myself, etc. I'm stuck on a lifetime issue. The closest question I could find that was already posted was:

[Argument requires that _ is borrowed for 'static - how do I work round this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58436950/argument-requires-that-is-borrowed-for-static-how-do-i-work-round-this)

The small project I'm playing around with defines two structs, `Agent` and `Item`.

The `Agent` struct contains, among other things, this line:

`pub inventory: HashMap<String, &'static Item>,`

Additionally, I've implemented this code:

```
impl Agent {
    
pub fn take_item(&mut self, item: &'static Item) -> std::result::Result<(), TestError> {
        if item.can_be_taken {
            if self.can_reach_item(item) {
                self.inventory.insert(item.name.to_string(), item);
                return Ok(());
            } else {
                return Err(ItemOutOfReachError {});
            }
        } else {
            return Err(ItemCannotBeTakenError {});
        }
    }
}
```

I've written a unit test which includes this line

```
let result = test_agent.take_item(&test_item);
```

I know there is a mistake somewhere because the compiler tells me:

```
  --> src/agent.rs:57:47
   |
57 |             let result = test_agent.take_item(&test_item);
   |                          ---------------------^^^^^^^^^^-
   |                          |                    |
   |                          |                    borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                          argument requires that `test_item` is borrowed for `'static`
...
```

I am passing the `test_item` as a reference to `take_item()` (or rather, `take_item()` is "borrowing" `test_item` if I'm using the jargon correctly). This seems to be the source of my error, but in the earlier post I linked, the author was able to solve the issue by adjusting the lifetime of the Option<> which contains the reference, as I understand it. In my example, I'm just using a bare reference to `test_item`. Is containing it, like the other author did, the recommended approach?

And the `'static` lifetime means that the `test_item` will essentially live for as long as the unit test is running?

I think my primary question boils down to, with what syntax must `take_item()` borrow the `test_item` in order for my code to be correct? And am I even thinking about this correctly?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: `'static` says the item lives _for as long as the program runs_; it's not valid for things that are _ever_ freed before exit, so it's clearly the wrong choice here unless the only things you're going to pass in the `item` slot are things that were defined/allocated in such a way as to ensure that they will never be freed.

Comment: The borrow is probably fine; you need to change the declaration of `take_item()`.

Comment: I'm realizing part of my issue is that I'm not clear on how the duration of non-static lifetimes is defined. The `'a` syntax is weird to me, though I'm seeking resources to help me understand. I appreciate the starting point @CharlesDuffy

Comment: The point of lifetimes like `'a` is that they tell you that something is defined to have _the same lifetime as something else that uses `'a` in the same context_. If nothing else uses `'a`, then using `'a` in a single place doesn't really add any information at all; whereas if you use `'a` for both a parameter and a return value, then you're saying the return value gets the same lifetime as the parameter.

Comment: Aha, light bulb. So they're relative. Gotcha.

Comment: So, something like this?

```
    pub fn take_item<'a>(&mut self, item: &'a Item) -> std::result::Result<(), TestError> {
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are specifying a lifetime to begin with? Was there an error saying that you needed one, or did you just make some decision to do so for another reason?

Comment: @Herohtar The CLion IDE and Rust compiler both warned me that to pass an item to this function, I would need to define a lifetime.
Also some reading up on it made it sound like it's something I need to do because the items might not need to persist forever.

Comment: @growling_egg Any reference has a lifetime, but it can be [elided](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html). Usually you don't need to specify lifetimes in function declarations. In structs, however, you do need.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The main problem in your code is that you used the `'static` lifetime in your struct.

I will try to explain what lifetimes are, how do they work and why you are facing this error. I warn you that this will be long and probably you will have doubts so at the end I am going to link a really good video where lifetimes are explained wonderfully.

**What are lifetimes?**

First of all, I will assume you have looked up some basic Rust terminology such as borrowing and moving and how rust's ownership works. If not I highly recommend you read the [Understanding Ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html) section in the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/).

So basically a lifetime is used by the rust compiler to define how long does a reference live in your program. Let's say we have the following code (taken from the book):

```rust
{
    let r;
    {
        let x = 4;
        r = &x;
    }
    println!("r: {}", r);
}
```

The above code will not compile because the *reference to x outlives the variable*. This means that while `x` will be dropped in when the end of the inner scope is reached, you are saving a reference to it in the outer scope. So when you reach the `println!` basically you have a reference to a variable that no longer "exists".

An easier way to understand this is to say that `r` lives longer than `x` and so you cannot save a reference of `x` into `r` because at some point `x` will have *died* and the reference stored in r will be invalid.

- `r` **has a longer lifetime than** `x`
- `r` **outlives** `x`

In order to keep track of these errors, the rust compiler makes use of identifiers. These can have almost any name preceded by a `'`. So `'a` is a valid lifetime as such as `'potato`. All references in Rust have a lifetime which is determined by how long they live (the scope they are in).

For example, in the code above there are two lifetimes:

```rust
{
    let r;                // ---------+-- 'a
                          //          |
    {                     //          |
        let x = 5;        // -+-- 'b  |
        r = &x;           //  |       |
    }                     // -+       |
                          //          |
    println!("r: {}", r); //          |
}                         // ---------+
```

So as `'a` outlives `'b` you cannot save a `&'b` reference into the `'a` lifetime.

**Lifetime elision**

Now you may be asking yourself why you don't see lifetime annotations often, this is called lifetime elision and is a process in which the rust compiler does a little work for you so that you can focus on programming instead of annotating all the references in your program. For example, given the following function:

```rust
fn takes_a_ref(name: &str) {
    ...
}
```

The rust compiler will define a new lifetime name for the scope corresponding to the brackets of the function automatically. You could annotate it using almost any name but the compiler uses the letters of the alphabet to define new lifetime names for the sake of simplicity. Let's say that the compiler chooses the letter `'a` then this function will be annotated automatically as:

```rust
fn takes_a_ref<'a>(name: &'a str) {
    ...
}
```

This means that the lifetime of `takes_a_ref` is called `'a` and that the reference you pass to `takes_a_ref` must point to a variable that lives at least as long as `'a` (the function).

The compiler does this automatically for you most of the time, but other times you must define the lifetime manually such as in structs.

```rust
pub struct MyStruct {
    pub field: &str
}
// Does not compile
```

Should be annotated as:

```rust
pub struct MyStruct<'a> {
    pub field: &'a str,
}
```

**Special lifetime names**

You've probably noted that I have been talking about *almost any name* when referring to the possibilities of naming lifetimes. This is because there exist a couple of reserved lifetime names that have special meanings:

- `'static`
- `'_`

The `'static` lifetime is a lifetime that corresponds to the entire lifetime of the program. This means that in order to obtain a reference with an `'static` lifetime the variable it points to must life from whenever the program is started until it is finished. An example is `const` variables:

```rust
const MY_CONST: &str = "Hello! "; // Here MY_CONST has an elided static lifetime
```

The `'_` lifetime is called the anonymous lifetime which is only a marker to point that there has been a lifetime elision in a variable. It will be replaced by the compiler compile time it only serves clarification porpoises.

**What is wrong with your code?**

So you have encountered the following situation:

1. You have created a struct called `Agent` which contains a `HashMap`.
2. This `HashMap` contains an owned `String` and a reference to an `Item`.
3. The compiler tells you that you must specify the lifetime of the `Item` as the compiler does not elide lifetimes in structs.
4. You have annotated `Item` with the `'static` lifetime.
5. Then you are forced to pass a `'static` reference in the `take_item` function as in some times you may save the item inside the struct's `HashMap` which now requires a `'static` lifetime of `Item`.

This now means that the reference to `Item` must point to an instance of `Item` that lives for the entirety of the program. For example:

```rust
fn function() {
    let mut agent = Agent::new();
    let my_item = Item::new();
    let result = agent.take_item(&item);
    ...
}

fn main() {
    function();
    // Do some other stuff. The scope of 'function' has ended and the variables dropped but the program has not ended! 'my_item' does not live for the entirety of the program.
}
```

You don't need `my_item` to live as long as the entirety of the program you need `my_item` to live as long as the `Agent` does. This is for any reference that will be stored inside the `Agent`, it just needs to live as long as it does the `Agent`.

**The solution (Option 1)**

Annotate `Agent` with a lifetime that is not the `'static` lifetime, for example:

```rust
pub struct Agent<'a> {
    pub items: HashMap<String, &'a Item>,
}

impl <'a> Agent<'a> {
    pub fn take_item(&mut self, item: &'a Item) -> std::result::Result<(), TestError> {
        ...
    }
}
```

This means that as long as the instance where the reference points lives as long as or more than the specific instance of `Agent` where it's stored there will be no problems. In the `take_item` function you specify:

> The lifetime of the variable where the reference points must be equal or longer than this `Agent`.

```rust
fn function() {
    let mut agent = Agent::new();
    let my_item = Item::new();
    let result = agent.take_item(&item);
    ...
}

fn main() {
    function();
    // No problem 
}
```

Will now compile fine.

Take in mind that you may have to start annotating functions in order to coerce the item to live as long as the Agent.

[Read more about lifetimes in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html).

**The solution (Option 2)**

Do you actually need the item to be stored as a reference inside the `Agent`? If the answer is NO then you can just pass the ownership of the `Item` to the agent:

```rust
pub struct Agent {
    pub items: HashMap<String, Item>,
}
```

In the implementation the function lifetime is elided automatically to live for as long as the function:

```rust
pub fn take_item(&mut self, item: &Item) {
    ...
}
```

So this is it. [Here you have a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juIINGuZyBc) from the YouTube channel Let's Get Rusty where lifetimes are explained.

Comment: A deeply helpful answer, thank you very much.

Indeed, I almost feel like the Agent should take ownership of the Item, as that's logically what's happening in the "space" of the program. I admit that I half-assumed that actually transferring ownership of a variable is maybe not a best practice, but your answer helps me understand it all much better. Cheers, friend.

Comment: I'm glad I was of help! Most of the time it makes no sense to borrow a variable to a struct if you don't need it anywhere else.